# impossible to encode and decode a message

Tags: java

I am trying to encode and decode a message through a XOR bitwise operator:

```
class Search {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   String msg = "This is a test";
   String encmsg = "";
   String decmsg = "";
   int key = 88;
   
   System.out.print("Original message: ");
   System.out.println(msg);
   
   
   // Encode the message.
   for(int i=0; i < msg.length(); i++)
       encmsg = encmsg + (char) (encmsg.charAt(i) ^ key);
   
   System.out.print("Encoded message: ");
   System.out.println(encmsg);
   
   // Decode the message
   for(int i=0; i < msg.length(); i++)
       decmsg = decmsg + (char) (decmsg.charAt(i) ^ key);
   
   System.out.print("Decoded message: ");
   System.out.println(decmsg);
  }
}
```

The output should be this:
Original message: This is a test
Encoded message: 01+x1+x9x,=+,
Decoded message: This is a test

This is what a receive:

```
Original message: This is a test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:711)
    at Package/Package.Search.main(Search.java:15)
```

Comment: Hint:  When your first loop executes for the first time, `i` is zero.  What is the value of `encmsg` when entering that loop for the first time?  What do you expect `encmsg.charAt(i)` to do?

Comment: Please check your code following 2 lines

 encmsg = encmsg + (char) (encmsg.charAt(i) ^ key);

decmsg = decmsg + (char) (decmsg.charAt(i) ^ key);

Try to identify from what stringyou are trying to retrieve the individual character.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up your original message and your encrypted one. The same thing with decryption. For example `encmsg = encmsg + (char) (encmsg.charAt(i) ^ key);` should have `msg.charAt(i)` instead of `encmsg.charAt(i)` because you should take chars from your original string, encode them and add to your already encoded part.

Here is the the proper way to code the logic:

```java
// Encode the message.
for(int i=0; i < msg.length(); i++)
    encmsg = encmsg + (char) (msg.charAt(i) ^ key);

System.out.print("Encoded message: ");
System.out.println(encmsg);

// Decode the message
for(int i=0; i < msg.length(); i++)
    decmsg = decmsg + (char) (encmsg.charAt(i) ^ key);
```

Comment: A code dump with no explanation is not a useful answer.  Explain what you changed and why you changed it.

Comment: Yes. Just fixed.